# How to create a directory that take the name of username in nodejs

Tags: node.js, api, express, file-upload, extract

I'm working on upload task with nodeJS (express), the goal is to upload a zip file contain some mp4 files, I want to extract the zip content on a directory that take the user name (req.user ) if not exist, or if it exist I do not need to recreate it just put the zip content inside.

can some explain how to do it technically, I finished the upload and the extract process but need to understand deeply how to do this task, I have thousand of user connected on my app.

**upload.js**

```
const util = require("util");
const multer = require("multer");
const maxSize = 10*1024*1024;

let storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, __basedir + "/resources/static/assets/uploads/zip");
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        req.zipFilePath = __basedir + "/resources/static/assets/uploads/zip/" + file.originalname
        cb(null, file.originalname);
    },
});

let uploadFile = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: {fileSize: maxSize},
}).single("zipFile");

let uploadFileMiddleware = util.promisify(uploadFile);
module.exports = uploadFileMiddleware;
```

**operationController**

```
async function upload(req, res) {
    console.log(req.user)
    const account = await getAccount(req.user.id);

    uploadFile(req, res).then(data => {
            fs.createReadStream(req.zipFilePath)
                .pipe(unzipper.Extract({path: __basedir + "/resources/static/assets/unzipped"}))
                .on('close', function (entry) {
                    fs.readdir(__basedir + "/resources/static/assets/unzipped", (err, files) => {
                        fs.unlink(req.zipFilePath, function (e) {
                            if (e) throw e;
                        });
                        return res.status(200).send({
                            message: "Uploaded the file successfully: " + req.file.originalname,
                        });
                    });
                });
        }
    ).catch(err => {
        return res.status(500).send({
            message: `Could not upload the file, ${err.message}`,
        });
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the directory exist with that username, but there is a catch as there might be users with same name. So, use uniqueID for every user and create a new directory if you have a new user.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var dir = `resources/static/assets/unzipped/${req.username}`;

if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){
    fs.mkdirSync(dir); //create new directory and write to it.
}
else {
// write stream to existing dir
}
```